# adb backup and restore, what is next?

Tags: adb, backup, restore

I have followed [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/246747) to backup and restore an app from my old to my new phone. I could make the backup and the restoration. My question might be a bit silly, but what is the next step to have your app running in the new phone as it was in the old phone? Should I have to install the same app from PlayStore and do something else? Does it has to be the same version of the app that was in the old one? Thanks, and sorry if the question is too obvious but I am new in this.

Comment: If you did a full backup (with the `-apk` parameter included), the app should be there already. Otherwise of course you'll need to install it. So hard to tell "what's next" if the relevant details are missing :)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  So, in case I  use `-noapk`. Should I install the app before or after doing the restoration?

Comment: I'd do it before, but that shouldn't really matter. Apart from that, I always use `-apk` – you can never tell if a given app is still available in the stores tomorrow.

Comment: I am using this command `adb backup -f backup.ab -apk -obb -shared -nosystem com.lbe.parallel.intl` And for being only one app it is taking so long already almost 30 min, and the size is 4GB and increasing. I am not sure if I should used `-shared`.

Comment: Another quest, if I I restore using `-noapk`, and if the version of the app that I install in my new phone is different, will it work anyway?

Comment: No; `-shared` means to include all contents of the SD card. And if you specify one app at the end, you can skip the `-nosystem` as well. And the `restore` command takes only one parameter: the file to restore from. No choice of pieces here.

Comment: Sorry I meant, if I backup using `-noapk`,  and then restore. then the version of the app that I install in my new phone (using PlayStore) have to be the same as in the old phone? Thanks @Izzy

Comment: Same or newer should be safe. Older you won't get anyway there.

Comment: I did not manage to restore my app :( So I went and try Helium. Then I notice than my app is marked as "disallowed" (to backup the data). Does it mean that I can not backup the data neither using `adb`? or `adb` is more "powerful" than Helium that I can backup a "disallowed" app?

Comment: Ah, there's your culprit. No, that app then can only be backed up using root powers. Developers can have their apps opt-out from "regular backups" by setting a corresponding flag (`ALLOW_BACKUP:NO`) in the app's Manifest. There's an Xposed module working around that – and there's *Titanium Backup* of course. But without root, no chance.

Comment: ok, if I root my old phone in order to make the backup, then should I root the new phone to make the restore too? I dont mind rooting the old phone, but the new one I would not like to.

Comment: I've never tried that on a non-rooted phone (wouldn't know where to get one in the first place – I usually root mine *before* unboxing ;) – but I'd expect that, if the `adb backup` managed the backup, it can be restored whether rooted or not. With TiBu things are different, as it needs root to run even for the restore. Note for the BackupAllApps module I mentioned you'd also need the Xposed framework.